# vertx-maven plugin : vertx_mods override issue

Tags: maven, vert.x

I am unable to pass mods directory information through VERTX_MODS environment variable / vertx.mods system property.

```
<groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

I get following error:

> org.vertx.java.platform.PlatformManagerException: Module  not found in any repositories

However, running vertx standalone works correctly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Found it ! set **modsDir property**

      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.vertx.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
      <modsDir><!--directory--></modsDir>
           <instances>1</instances>
           <classpath>src/main/resources/:src/test/resources/:target/classes/:target/test-classes/</classpath>
        </configuration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments:

> Found it ! set modsDir property  io.vertx
>   vertx-maven-plugin
>   ${maven.vertx.plugin.version} 
>    1
>   src/main/resources/:src/test/resources/:target/classes/:target/test-c‌​lasses/
>    –  everCurious Jul 25 '14 at 15:02